# Creating XML on the fly (memory) in ASP.NET and displaying in browser

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, wcf-rest

I am trying to create an API XML which has data coming from MySQL database. I am trying to acheive something like below.

```
<api xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <key>eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb</key>
    <name>API Test</name>
    <feedState>Test</feedState>
    <news href="http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb/news/"/>
    <comments href="http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb/comments/"/>
</api>
```

I can see the above XML if I open my browser and type in the below URL

```
http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb
```

Now if I need to see details within "news" I will simple point my browser now to,

```
http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb/news
```

After doing that I will see something like,

```
<news xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" state="Trial">
 <newsListItem href="http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb/news/800577419/">
   <id>800577419</id>
   <publishDate>2011-08-17</publishDate>
   <lastModifiedDate>2011-08-17</lastModifiedDate>
   <headline>Google buys Motorola</headline>
</newsListItem>
<newsListItem href="http://api.mydomain.com/eee83d24-906b-4736-91d9-1031621b79eb/news/800577416/">
   <id>800577416</id>
   <publishDate>2011-08-17T15:13:12</publishDate>
   <lastModifiedDate>2011-08-17T15:14:36</lastModifiedDate>
   <headline>Apple Macbook Air</headline>
 </newsListItem>
</news>
```

Remember all the data shown above comes from MySQL Database.

How can I achieve the above? Any examples samples, ideas are welcome. I would be obliged if someone can throw a light. Is WCF the way to go? or using plain old ASP.NET XDoc etc...?

Please advise. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use WCF REST service and return your XML easily. Simply create a project using Visual Studio Project template found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd).
If you already have classes defined that reads data from MySQL database, you can return them and have WCF serialize it for you. This way you dont have to use XDoc/XElement to build XML.
The method and service class would look something like:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class APIService
{
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{key}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
  public APIData GetAPIData(string key)
  {
    // build apiData object from DB using "key"
    return apiData
  }

  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{key}/news", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
  public APINewsData GetAPINewsData(string key)
  {
    // build apiNewsData object from DB using "key"
    return apiNewsData
  }


}
```

If you use XmlSerializer class (by specifying [xmlSerializerFormat] attribute like above) instead of DataContractSerializer class (default WCF serializer) you can have more control on how the return XML looks. But it is slower than the default option. More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I used RouteTables with XDoc and XElement to create the XML. WCF had a bit of its limitations as per the application structure we had, so didn't wanted to go with that. But appreciate the response.